# Determine accuracy of model which estimates probability of one of the classes

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-mining, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm modeling an event with two outcomes, 0(rejection) and 1(acceptance). I have created a model which estimates the probability that 1(acceptance) will happen (i.e. the model will calculate that '1' will happen with 80% chance or in other words probability of acceptance is 0.8)

Now, I have a large record of outcomes of trials with the estimates from the model (For example: probability of acceptance=0.8 and actual class (acceptance=1)). I would like to quantify or validate how accurate the model is. Is this possible, and if so how?

Note: I am just predicting probability of class 1. Let's say prediction for class 1 is 0.8 and the actual class value is 1. Now I want to find performance of my model.

Comment: Accuracy, precision, recall, AUC, binary crossentropy, MSE, MAE, etc. are all metrics you can use

Comment: But AUC will require binary outputs so we can create confusion matrix and then plot. But In my case, i won't be able to create confusion matrix. I am predicting probability of class 1 (acceptance) and I will require to compare it with 1. Any thoughts?

Comment: AUC neither requires a binary output, nor a confusion matrix. It needs a score per object that can be used to sort objects. You need a binary reference for evaluation only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to convert your probability to one of two discrete classes with thresholded rounding, i.e. if p(y=1|x)>0.5: predict 1, else predict 0. Then all of the metrics are applicable. The threshold can be chosen by inspecting the ROC curve and/or precision-recall changes or can be simply set to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the objects by prediction.

Then compute the ROC AUC of the resulting curve.